# ResourceAssembler not returning the right path(created resource path) in response _links

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a controller to `POST` jobs of a user. On successful creation, the response should contain the created resource's link. For that I wrote the below `ResourceAssembler`

```
public class UserJobResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<UserJob, Resource<UserJob>>  {

    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    public UserJobResourceAssembler(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<UserJob> toResource(UserJob entity) {
        Resource<UserJob> resource = new Resource<>(entity);
        resource.add(
                entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(UserJob.class, entity.getId()).withSelfRel()
                );
        return resource;
    }

}
```

And this is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles" )
@ExposesResourceFor(UserJob.class)
public class UserJobController {

    private UserJobService userJobService;

    public UserJobController(UserJobService userJobService) {
        this.userJobService = userJobService;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/{uniqueId}/jobs")
    public Resource<UserJob> createJob(@Valid @RequestBody UserJob userJob, final Principal principal, @PathVariable String uniqueId) {

        return userJobService.save(userJob, principal.getName(), uniqueId);

    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/{uniqueId}" + JOBS + "/{jobId}")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Resource<UserJob> getSingleJob(@PathVariable String uniqueId, @PathVariable String jobId) {
        System.out.println("get single job for job id: " + jobId);

        return new Resource<UserJob>(new UserJob());
    }

}
```

`uniqueId` is the id of the user for which this job is being created.
Though the `ResourceAssembler` creates link but a wrong one.

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles/12"
        }
  }
```

I was expecting it to be `http://localhost:8085/api/v1/profiles/theCoder/jobs/12`

I know this is not the issue with `ResourceAssembler` but with the `EntityLinks`. And this can be solved by using `linkTo` instead of `EntityLinks`

```
resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(UserJobController.class).getSingleJob(entity.getUser().getUniqueId(), entity.getUserJobId().toString())).withSelfRel());
```

But I want to implement this in DRY principle and using the controller classes would stop me to make it DRY.

What are the alternatives/solutions?

Answer (score 2):

In the resource processor, you are setting the self link to the URL for UserJob (/profiles which you have set in your controller) and concatenating the id, so it becomes "/profiles/id".

If you need to set a link to the URL of a method, ControllerLinkBuilder is the best option to avoid hardcoding URLs (which would be needed if you use EntityLinks):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/{uniqueId}/jobs")
public Resource<UserJob> createJob(@Valid @RequestBody UserJob userJob, final Principal principal, @PathVariable String uniqueId) {

    UserJob userJob = userJobService.save(userJob, principal.getName(), uniqueId);
    return toResource(userJob);

}

private Resource<UserJob> toResource(UserJob userJob) {
    Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(UserJobController.class)
        .getSingleJob(/* values */))
        .withSelfRel();

    return new Resource<>(userJob, selfLink);
}
```